# Zoom delphi TPanel contents (changing DPI)

Tags: delphi, winapi, dpi

I created a Report Designer years ago.

All components (labels, expressions, etc) of the report structure are represented by TLabels.

Bands of the report are represented by TPanels....

The component designer currently uses default pixels per inch (96).

Now I need to change the scale, to "zoom" the design and enhance the production.

My question is, how can I do zoom/scale on the contents of an TPanel? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `ScaleControl` method. It is protected so you'll need a helper or the protected hack to access the method.

Comment: Works, but I cannot change the Width and Height of the internal controls. I need to maintain them and only increase the proportion.

Comment: If you aren't going to scale the children, what are you doing beyond scaling the parent?

Comment: The best solution for me can be changing the PixelsPerInch of my container, is this possible?

Comment: A panel does not have a pixels per inch. You would do better to explain what you are trying to do.